# Read a file without saving it locally python/bottle

Tags: python, bottle

Hi so basically I have a form that uploads a file

```
 <input class="btn btn-light" type="file" id="file" name="h" accept=".py">
```

I'm using bottle, so essentially I want to get the contents of the file but not have to save it locally. Using with open requires a path which I don't have as it is not saved locally.

```
f = request.POST['file']
```

I get the file using the above.

Is there any way I could upload the file without having to save it locally?

Any help would be much appreciated, I just need the name of the file and the contents.

Comment: You're looking for `io.BytesIO`

Answer (score 2):

No need to save the file (or to use BytesIO as suggested in a comment). You can simply read its contents:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload():
    f = request.POST["file_name"]
    text = f.file.read()
    return f"Read {len(text)} bytes from the uploaded file.\n"

app.run()
```

Output:

```
$ echo "This is the file to upload." > file.txt
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload -F file_name=@file.txt
Read 28 bytes from the uploaded file.
```